# Form validation of a name php including apostrophe, space, hyphen and period

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having a hard time putting the correct expression together, so that it rejects everything except letters, periods, apostrophes, spaces and hyphens.

So far this works for everything except the apostrophe, which I've tried to escape with both single and double "\" to no avail.

```
  if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'. -]+$/",$_POST['name']))
  {
      $error_name="The name you entered is invalid.";
  }
 //obrien - pass
 //o'brien - fail
 //Dr. OBrien - pass
 //Dr. O'Brien - fail
```

This works perfectly except that no apostrophe clears it.

Comment: This should work perfectly fine. What issues are you facing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Could you update your question with the value of `$_POST['name']` that doesn't pass your test?

Comment: It still rejects the apostrophe like in O'Brien

Comment: With this regex, `- ..--` is a valid name!!!

Comment: but I'm very open to a better one.

Comment: @AuntJamaima: What exactly are you trying to validate? Doesn't sound like this is for a *name* to me.

Comment: I was trying to validate a name. I am open to other means of validating a name.

Comment: $lastname = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-\']/', '', $lastname); -- I use this one for backend validation on names - seems to work ok.

Comment: @TimSPQR That's not validation, that's replacement...

Answer (score 3):

The problem ended up being that in the php.ini that I can't access on my godaddy account, addslashes must be enabled. The following made it work. Thank you to Sergey for leading me to think about what the server might be doing to the posted data.

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z'. -]+$/", stripslashes($_POST['name']))
{
whatever error message
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an amazing one I was able to come up with, I think it should be able to work with most names that have both hypens, apostrophes, spaces and so on.

```
    if(!preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]+[\'-]?[a-zA-Z]+[ ]?)+$/', $string))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it happens because you are trying to check url-encoded string. Replace `$_POST['name']` with `urldecode($_POST['name'])`. The apostrophe at this stage looks like `%27`, so O'Brien in $_POST['name'] is **O%27Brien** and it will not pass your regular expression.

**Edit:** Also, maybe it is another type of apostrophe you have entered in the form: `’`.

As a result:

```
if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z’'. -]+$/",urldecode($_POST['name'])) {
    $error_name="The name you entered is invalid.";
}
```

Comment: Yes, but why `Dr. OBrien` pass? The space must be `%20`.

Comment: Or a + sign. But you are right, initial regular expression must not accept plus sign too. I will update my answer with new variant.

Comment: Brilliant my problem was with the apostrophe `'` I wasn't checking for type of apostrophe `’`